# Why 5V instead of 3V3?

Tags: voltage

I'm still quite new to electronics, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

I was wondering why virtually all the example circuits I find use the 5V power supply with resistors for all the components instead of the 3V3 power supply directly.

Even for the most simplistic "Blink" example, they use 5V pin and a 220 Ohm resistor to protect the LED instead of using the built-in 3.3V pin.

Yes, I know that in former times "everything" ran on 5V, but since we already have a lower voltage built-in, why not use it and reduce the number of components needed?

TIA for anyone who can solve this puzzle for me.
mav

Comment: Could you give an example of a circuit that uses 5V for the supply and resistors for all the components? My guess is that these resistors would still be necessary even if the circuit ran on 3.3V (possibly with different values). For example, the current through an LED should always be limited (by a resistor or otherwise), regardless of what voltage supply it's connected through. With a 3.3V supply you would still need a resistor although possibly a lower value.

Comment: The reason that you will still find many examples using 5V is that the "classic" Arduino Uno that many hobbyists start out with still runs on 5V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, even with 3.3V, an LED needs a resistor to limit the current through it. So, running with 3.3V doesn't solve that particular problem. Try Googling for "LED current limiting resistor".

Second, many Arduinos are designed to run using 5V. In many cases they have an input power jack which can accept a range of voltages and use a voltage regulator to convert it down to 5V,

Why not convert down to 3.3V you might ask? Well, the higher the voltage, the faster the processor can run, within its design limits. For example, the Atmega328P (which is in the Arduino Uno, and others) could only run at 13 MHz at 3.3V rather than 16 MHz.

> ... instead of using the built-in 3.3V pin

But that pin is only provided for convenience. You can't turn it on or off by a program.

The higher voltage (5V vs 3.3V) can be more convenient in some situations, for example switching motors on and off, or with other devices designed to work with 5V.

Motors or other high-power devices are typically turned on with MOSFET transistors. To be efficient, they need to fully turn on (have a low resistance between Source and Drain) and even so-called "logic level" MOSFETs typically require 5V to fully turn them on, rather than 3.3V. If you tried to control a motor with a 3.3V based board you would probably need extra components to turn the MOSFET on properly, so lowering the voltage could potentially add components, not reduce them.

On the other hand, many components these days are designed to work with 3.3V (or lower) so the choice of 5V is a bit of a compromise.

Comment: Also: USB, which is a very common way of powering devices these days, is 5V by default (extending to higher voltages on request with USB-C Power Delivery)

Comment: "For example, the Atmega328P could only run at 13 MHz at 3.3V rather than 16 MHz" is a  bit confusing, given that faster CPUs use lower voltages. But the reason is obviously not the same.

Comment: @PMF _But_, those faster CPUs that allow runtime frequency scaling generally also scale down voltage at lower frequencies, and most people who intentionally underclock their system do so so they can also under-volt it (and therefore save power).

Comment: @PMF - I am just quoting (extrapolating) from the figures in the datasheet. In the case of the Atmega328P, there are speed limits depending on voltage. And you can actually use less power by using a lower voltage, trading off speed for power savings. For various reasons, heat probably being the main one, modern high-speed CPUs would indeed use lower voltages, but they would be designed with that in mind.

Comment: @NickGammon That was what I was talking about. Higher voltages result in higher heat losses. And if you want to overclock a CPU, you typically have to increase the voltage (to make sure the electronics can properly switch from high to low) - and install a large heat sink.